# How to flag all records with matching id when one fits the criteria

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find a way to create a flag, within SQL. What I want to be flagged, is if there is a memid that has 1 in NumberofTransactions, but for all repeating memid's.

So in the screenshot, I have a table with 2 example records. They have the same memid, but different details. But because one of these memid's has 1 in Number of Transactions, I want the Flag column to be populated for both of them, to let me know that at least one of them has 1 transaction.

[image]

This is what I would like my results to look like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN number_of_transactions = 1 THEN 'Yes' END) OVER(PARTITION BY memid) as flag
FROM table t
```

or

```
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 where t1.memid = t.memid AND number_of_transactions = 1) 
        THEN 'Yes'
    END as flag
FROM table t
```

I reckon the first query might be quicker.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you so much! Just a question though, I'm trying to get my head around the use of the MAX function in the first query, as I'm a bit confused with it.

Comment: @MWong it's called a 'window function'. You should read up on it (it's extremely useful): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html